# Editing column header of a datagridview

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, header

Guys I need to get all the headers of my datagridview in a combobox and then on selection from the combobox I get the header in a textbox and when I modify In the textbox

1.I get the modified header in the combobox.

2.I get the modified header in the datagridview also.

I did the following

```
  //fill in the combobox with the ACTUAL headers of the list box.
      for (int i = 0; i <= listselected.columns.Count(); i++)
       {
                        comboedit.Items.Add(listselected.gridview.Columns[i].HeaderText);

                        comboedit.SelectionChanged += (sende, eee) =>
                        {
                            //on user selection, display choice in textbox for editing
                            textedit.Text = comboedit.SelectedItem.ToString();

                        };

                    }  
                    textedit.TextChanged += (sende, eee) =>
                    {//display EDITED text as header of the list box
                        listselected.gridview.Columns[comboedit.SelectedIndex].HeaderText = textedit.Text;   
                    };
```

However with this code I get only the modified header in the datagridview,the combobox is not updated.

How should I modify the codes to do what i want ?

Comment: 1)Did you alter the DataGridView Template in order for the headers to be "Editable" (I'm just trying to understand what editing the column header means) .
2) Please post your XAML for your GridView and ComboBox

Comment: By editing the column headers means that I change the header text by editing it in the textbox after chosing which one to edit from a combobox.

Comment: Yes i got that , but is that a built in feature for the DataGridView ?

Comment: No, I am doing all this in a toolbox(my toolbox) on another window.

Comment: I want to know where are you changing the Column Header's Text

Comment: textedit.TextChanged += (sende, eee) =>
                    {//display EDITED text as header of the list box
                        listselected.gridview.Columns[comboedit.SelectedIndex].HeaderText = textedit.Text;
                       
                    };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to update combobox text try this

```
comboedit.SelectedItem.Text = textedit.Text;
```

in

```
textedit.TextChanged += (sende, eee) =>
```